# Is it possible with Mongo DB to select data based on 2 IDs in Mondo DB document?

Tags: arrays, excel, database, mongodb, nosql

I have an array dataset ( first column is list of cities, second and other columns contain distance between selected city from first column and selected city in second and other columns ).

Tried to use many to many relationship in SQL Server, but it seems to complicated and nearly impossible.
For now i have 2 options for implementing main task.

My main task is to select distance between 2 cities based on 2 dropdown selections, which data source is city from fitst column and selected city in second and others column.

Is it possible in Mongo DB to solve this task ? I am not sure, if i can query a bson document based on 2 IDs ( first ID is city from first column and second ID is city from other column ).

Please help

Comment: Some sample data and an expected result would be really helpful here.

Comment: @Joe , here is the sample data

Inbound city Plecetskiy Korosten       Ternove
Irpen         61                 75                86
Bucha         32                 24                36
Gostomel         34                 56                35

Comment: Is that a single document?

Comment: @Joe, yes, it's a single document